Induction on well-founded sets, why only minimal elements sufficient?
I'm confused by the concept of induction on well-founded and on well-ordered set and I need your help please.
On well-ordered set, we can do induction on it. Each subset of the set has its least element.
Whereas, following the defition of well-founded on Wikipedia (the first paragraph of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation), each subset of a well-founded set is guaranteed to have a minimal element. In the same article, it is said that we can also do induction on well-founded set.
Here the difference between the existence of least element on well-ordered set and of minimal element on well-founded confuses me alot.
For well-ordered set, I understand that we need some least elements to ensure that there is certainly some "starting point". I think it is the same for well-founded set, but it requires only existence of minimal elements, which means that there exists (maybe, infinitely ?) elements which are incomparable (which means that how can we evenly suppose that a given property is true for every set smaller than a set $x$ in the hypothesis of induction process when some sets maybe incomparable to $x$ ? I think there is a chance that a given property fails on those incomparable sets).
So why it is always possible for induction (defined in the section "induction and recursion" of the same page on Wikipedia) to be hold on a well-founded set while there are elements which aren't comparable ?
Thank you very much for your help!!

The article you link to doesn't seem to be completely clear on that, but I suppose that to prove that property $P$ holds in a well-founded set $A$, you have to start by proving $P(m)$ for every minimal element $m$ of $A$ (in place of P(0) in $\mathbb N$), and then proceed with induction step: if $P(y)$ for every $y<x$ then $P(x)$. That's what I think that makes sense.

A well-ordering is a special case of a well-founded relation. It might be good to think about ordinary mathematical induction on the natural numbers, which is a special case of both. The version of induction that is most easily generalizable is sometimes called strong induction:  $$ \forall x(\forall y < x P(y)\to P(x)) \to \forall xP(x).$$
This holds for any well-founded relation $<.$ The reason is simple. If $P(x)$ fails for any $x,$ there is a minimal counterexample $x$. But then, by minimality, $\forall y< x P(y)$ holds, so $P(x)$ needs to hold after all.
So the basic natural argument really just works with minimal elements of well-founded relations, not just with least elements and well-orders. The possibility of incomparability just means instead of having a least element to start with, we have a set $A_0$ of minimal elements of $(X,<),$ and instead of a successor to the least element, we have the set $A_1$ of minimal elements of $X\setminus A_0.$ The predecessors of the elements of $A_1$ will all necessarily be in $A_0$, so if have the the proposition is true for all the elements of $A_0$, and we can infer the truth of the proposition from its truth for any predecessessors, then we have truth for all the elements of $A_1$ too. And then we can continue on. So it works much the same way, only many elements at a time rather than one element at a time. (As the $0$ and $1$ subscripts suggest, you can also think of this as an induction on ordinal “levels”, often called “rank”.)
